# How to create annotation title in multiple line in iOS

Tags: ios, annotations, title, mkannotationview

In my application i want to create annotation title in multiple line to display whole address line. Please resolved my problem

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     CLLocationCoordinate2D pinlocation;
        double lat=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"21.191536"] doubleValue];

        double longi=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"72.804672"] doubleValue];
        pinlocation.latitude = lat; //set latitude of selected coordinate ;
        pinlocation.longitude = longi; //set longitude of selected coordinate;

        // Create Annotation point
        MKPointAnnotation *Pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        Pin.coordinate = pinlocation;
        Pin.title =@"ss";

       Pin.subtitle = [SalonSetting GetAddressline];
        self.centerAnnotation = Pin;

        // add annotation to mapview
        [self.salonAddressMap addAnnotation:Pin];
        //zoom ocation
        CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
        zoomLocation.latitude = pinlocation.latitude;
        zoomLocation.longitude= pinlocation.longitude;
        // 2
        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

        [self.salonAddressMap setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: show your code what you tried , else add [yourLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

Comment: i have no idea about this . And i research a lot  but i can't find any solution

Comment: Show your code in viewForAnnotation method

Comment: Please check my code . i don't override any method for this

Comment: Have you solved this issue

Comment: @Stela  I am also facing same problem,could you please post your answer, How to show multiple lines on annotation title .?

Comment: On the detail view you set the a label and set label numbelOflines=0, and text mode word wrapping.

Comment: Wait I will send u my demo project link

Comment: Could you please send the your demo project link?

Comment: yes pls wait , let me find demo

Comment: @SaurabhJain hiiii

Comment: @MonikaPatel send the link of demo project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117682/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-saurabh-jain).